# query kusto database for DB availability

Tags: database, azure-data-explorer, kql, availability

What is the query to check DB availability of all DBs within a cluster?

I came across few HTTP methods but no direct Kusto Query to directly run on the explorer

Answer (score 2):

from your original question, it's not fully clear what you define as 'DB availability'.

if you want to see which databases are available to query (in terms of existence, and the caller being authorized as a 'viewer' or a higher privilege) - you can run the `.show cluster databases` control command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/show-cluster-database

Comment: again - the definition of a database being 'up and running' isn't clear. maybe you could clarify what in the result set of `.show cluster databases` (see answer above) is missing compared to your requirement?

Comment: a. i think you're referring to database/cluster interchangeably, though they are very different terms; b. for monitoring your *cluster*'s availability, you can use the `keep alive` metric, mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-metrics#supported-azure-data-explorer-metrics